# How to fix in-game double-click issue in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, mouse, double-click

I have this issue with double clicking in-game. I wrote this code that checks for input and returns the type of input it received.

In editor it works just fine, but when I export the game it always returns double click type. Even if I click just once. Not sure what's causing this issue..

Below is the mouse input script and other is how I use it in other scripts.

**Mouse Input script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MouseInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables

    private enum ClickType      { None, Single, Double }

    private static ClickType    currentClick    = ClickType.None;
    readonly float              clickdelay      = 0.25f;

    #endregion

    void OnEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InputListener());
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public static bool SingleMouseClick()
    {
        if (currentClick == ClickType.Single)
        {
            currentClick = ClickType.None;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public static bool DoubleMouseClick()
    {
        if (currentClick == ClickType.Double)
        {
            currentClick = ClickType.None;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private IEnumerator InputListener()
    {
        while (enabled)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            { yield return ClickEvent(); }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator ClickEvent()
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) yield break;

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        currentClick = ClickType.Single;
        float count = 0f;
        while (count < clickdelay)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                currentClick = ClickType.Double;
                yield break;
            }
            count += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (MouseInput.SingleMouseClick())
{
    Debug.Log("Single click");
    Select(true);
}
else if (MouseInput.DoubleMouseClick())
{
    Debug.Log("Double click");
    Select(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on the frame `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` evaluates to true you call into `ClickEvent()` which then yields on `WaitForEndOfFrame();` then eventually gets back to another `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`.

You problem is that [`WaitForEndOfFrame()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html) waits until the *end of the current frame*:

> Waits until the end of the frame after all cameras and GUI is
>   rendered, just before displaying the frame on screen.

It doesn't wait until the *next frame*.  Because of this, all values returned by the `Input` API are still going to be the same.  You want a `yield return null` instead of `WaitForEndOfFrame()`.